# Mocha with Chai HTTP async testing?

Tags: node.js, async-await, mocha.js, chai

I'm testing a Rest API using Mocha and Chai HTTP. I've been writing all of the tests cases using callbacks and now I want to use async/await because is a lot more readable tan callbacks and promises, so I get this code:

```
let sport1, sport2;
let user1, user2;
let user1Token;
let event1, event2, event3, event4;

beforeEach(async function () {
  const preUser1 = test.createUser('user1@test.com');
  const preUser2 = test.createUser('user2@test.com')

  sport1 = await Sport.create(test.createSport('Tenis'));
  sport2 = await Sport.create(test.createSport('Baloncesto'));
  user1 = await User.create(preUser1);
  user2 = await User.create(preUser2);
  event1 = await Event.create(test.createEventDb(user1._id, sport1._id));
  event2 = await Event.create(test.createEventDb(user1._id, sport2._id));
  event3 = await Event.create(test.createEventDb(user2._id, sport1._id));
  event4 = await Event.create(test.createEventDb(user2._id, sport2._id));

  await chai.request(app)
    .post(`${apiPath}/sessions`)
    .set('content-type', 'application/json')
    .send({ email: preUser1.email, password: preUser1.password })
    .end(function (err, res) {
      console.log(res.body)
      user1Token = res.body.data.session.token;
    });
});
```

The await statements are working fine, but the problem here is with chai. I'm getting this error:

```
1) Events "before each" hook for "should return 200, id and event info":
 TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
    at ClientRequest.end (_http_outgoing.js:605:11)
    at Test.Request.end (node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:873:9)
    at node_modules/superagent/lib/request-base.js:72:12
    at Test.then (node_modules/superagent/lib/request-base.js:71:31)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

But this error is not raising without the async/await call. Any idea on what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: hmm, they don't use `.end` in the chai HTTP promise [example](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/). Instead they call `.then` to get the response. So if I understand the promise example right: with async/await you would save the response in a variable (instead of calling `.then`) and then call `expect` (or any other assertion function of your liking).

Comment: That's true, I didn't notice that they don't use the `.end()` method when using promises. It's working perfectly saving the response in a variable and making the assertions after, thanks!

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question :)

Answer (score 13):

As @Rhayene mentioned, to use Chai with promises you can't use the `.end()` method, that's why I'm getting that error. So instead, you only store the response in a variable and then make the needed assertions. So, my refactored code is this:

```
let sport1, sport2;
let user1, user2;
let user1Token;
let event1, event2, event3, event4;

beforeEach(async function () {
  const preUser1 = test.createUser('user1@test.com');
  const preUser2 = test.createUser('user2@test.com')

  sport1 = await Sport.create(test.createSport('Tenis'));
  sport2 = await Sport.create(test.createSport('Baloncesto'));
  user1 = await User.create(preUser1);
  user2 = await User.create(preUser2);
  event1 = await Event.create(test.createEventDb(user1._id, sport1._id));
  event2 = await Event.create(test.createEventDb(user1._id, sport2._id));
  event3 = await Event.create(test.createEventDb(user2._id, sport1._id));
  event4 = await Event.create(test.createEventDb(user2._id, sport2._id));

  const res = await chai.request(app)
    .post(`${apiPath}/sessions`)
    .set('content-type', 'application/json')
    .send({ email: preUser1.email, password: preUser1.password })

  user1Token = res.body.data.session.token;
});
```